# Android AlarmManager not working

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

In my main activity, I am executing this:

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // 9:45 PM 
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MorningReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(NotificationScanner.this,
                "Scheduled: " + calendar.getTime(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();
```

And this is my receiver

```
public class MorningReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM); 
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            Intent skype = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");
            context.startActivity(skype);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(context,
                "Exception thrown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();
    }
}
```

}

The Toast from the main activity displays, so I know the alarm is getting set, but the receiver is never getting called (the ring is never playing, nor the Toast exception message). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here with my AlarmManager? Am I supposed to do something in my Manifest to get the Receiver working?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to log? It may happen that due to some reason its not going in the `If condition`.

Comment: @LalitPoptani I just logged it and found it said "Unable to start service Intent { ....... (has extras) }: not found" so I added "<receiver android:name="MorningReceiver" >
        </receiver>". Now its not showing anything about MorningReceiver.

Comment: put below line of code in androidmanifest.xml file it might solve your procblem .                                                     <receiver android:name="MorningReceiver" ></receiver>